# Sampler referencing in HLSL - Sampler parameter must come from a literal expression

Tags: xna, hlsl

The following method works fine when referencing a sampler in HLSL

```
    float3 P = lightScreenPos;
sampler ShadowSampler = DPFrontShadowSampler;
float depth;

if (alpha >= 0.5f)
{
    // Reference the correct sampler
    ShadowSampler = DPFrontShadowSampler;

    // Front hemisphere 'P0'
    P.z = P.z + 1.0;
    P.x = P.x / P.z;
    P.y = P.y / P.z;
    P.z = lightLength / LightAttenuation.z;

    // Rescale viewport to be [0, 1] (texture coordinate space)
    P.x = 0.5f * P.x + 0.5f;
    P.y = -0.5f * P.y + 0.5f;

    depth = tex2D(ShadowSampler, P.xy).x;
    depth = 1.0 - depth;
}
else
{
    // Reference the correct sampler
    ShadowSampler = DPBackShadowSampler;

    // Back hemisphere 'P1'
    P.z = 1.0 - P.z;
    P.x = P.x / P.z;
    P.y = P.y / P.z;
    P.z = lightLength / LightAttenuation.z;

    // Rescale viewport to be [0, 1] (texture coordinate space)
    P.x = 0.5f * P.x + 0.5f;
    P.y = -0.5f * P.y + 0.5f;

    depth = tex2D(ShadowSampler, P.xy).x;
    depth = 1.0 - depth;
}

// [Standard Depth Calculation]
float mydepth = P.z;
shadow = depth + Bias.x < mydepth ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
```

If I try and do anything with the sampler reference outside the if statement then I get the following error:

*Sampler parameter must come from a literal expression*

This code demonstrates that

```
    float3 P = lightScreenPos;
sampler ShadowSampler = DPFrontShadowSampler;

if (alpha >= 0.5f)
{
    // Reference the correct sampler
    ShadowSampler = DPFrontShadowSampler;

    // Front hemisphere 'P0'
    P.z = P.z + 1.0;
    P.x = P.x / P.z;
    P.y = P.y / P.z;
    P.z = lightLength / LightAttenuation.z;
}
else
{
    // Reference the correct sampler
    ShadowSampler = DPBackShadowSampler;

    // Back hemisphere 'P1'
    P.z = 1.0 - P.z;
    P.x = P.x / P.z;
    P.y = P.y / P.z;
    P.z = lightLength / LightAttenuation.z;
}

// Rescale viewport to be [0, 1] (texture coordinate space)
P.x = 0.5f * P.x + 0.5f;
P.y = -0.5f * P.y + 0.5f;

// [Standard Depth Calculation]
float depth = tex2D(ShadowSampler, P.xy).x;
depth = 1.0 - depth;
float mydepth = P.z;
shadow = depth + Bias.x < mydepth ? 0.0f : 1.0f;
```

How can I reference the sampler in this manner without triggering the error?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried to create a function and pass it as an argument?

Comment: That works but I end up with lots of functions with many arguments.  It's a solution of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your pixel shader:

```
sampler NormalSampler : register(s1);
```

And this in your C#:

```
graphics.GraphicsDevice.Textures[1] = normalTexture;
```